# Regex for extracting meta data

Tags: php, regex

I have retrieved html page using cURL, now I want to extract the specific meta content from the meta data. i.e. `<meta name="ids" content="123nsdfsdfAS">`.

What I did as follows:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("http://example.com");
```

So, I want to extract a specific meta content i.e. `<meta name="ids" content="123nsdfsdfAS">` from `$html` using `preg_match_all` or `preg_match` or related any function and regular expression. I have written a regex but that is not good, so I did not mention here.

Comment: post the regex you tried.

Comment: I have tried: `preg_match_all('#<meta(?:\s+?([^\=]+)\=\"(.+?)\")+?\s*?/?>#sui', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);`

Comment: it works https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here it's fairly easy:

```
/<meta[^>]+>/
```

will match any meta tag.

```
/<meta name="ids"[^>]+>/
```

will match only the meta tag with the name `ids`.

If you only want the content in this

```
/<meta name="ids" content="([^"]+)">/
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `<meta name="ids"(.*?)>`.  easy way... $1 will give you the attributes

Answer (score 0):

Below regex match meta element

```
<meta(?: [^>]+)?>

ex:
<meta>
<meta id="12"> any attribute

<meta(?: [^>]+)? id="([^"]*)"[^>]*>

ex:
<meta id="123">
<meta id="123" content="cnt">
```